# How can I make this sentence better?

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms, lyrics

I am going to say something in English but I don't know what are the **best words** or **grammatical method** for expression of it?

*This is the concept :*

> **"Soul is the point at the center of art circle"** or **"Soul is the
>   central point of art circle"**

Do you have any idea for replacing of some of words in that sentence by better synonyms!

I need your technical offers.

Comment: Central to all art is the soul.  At the center of all art you will find the soul.  The center of all art is rooted in the soul.  Or, depending on how narrowly or liberally you define *art*: The soul is found at the center of any art of consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it sound a little poetic, I would like to offer a few alternatives, in addition to J.R.'s answer:

> ***Soul is to art as center is to a circle.***
>
> ***Soul is where the center of the circle of art lies.***

Answer (score 2):

> ***Soul is at the center of the circle of art***.

Your word choices seem fine; I don't see a need to replace any particular word with a better-suited synonym.

However, I think there are better ways to express the notion of being at the center of a circle. I've made two fundamental changes to your original; these are:

1. I don't think we need to include the word *point*; the center of a circle is by definition a single point. I assume you are trying to express this in a poetic, philosophical way, and I think that can be accomplished more effectively by removing the word *point*.
2. Also, there is nothing grammatically wrong with *art circle*, although I think you'll find that, in English, expression *the circle of X* is used [more frequently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circle%20of%20life,life%20circle,circle%20of%20love,love%20circle&year_start=1950&year_end=1980&corpus=15&smoothing=3) in this metaphorical context than *the X circle* (as is *the sphere of X*, as opposed to *the X sphere*). For example, expressions such as *sphere of influence* and *circle of friends* are quite common. Therefore, I think *circle of art* flows a little better than *art circle*.

My rewording is also a bit alliterative: the words *soul*, *center*, and *circle* are now all close together. That was just coincidental, but I think it works in the expression's favor.

Comment: thanks a lot , indeed i am trying to express that in a poetic, philosophical way ,  this is main reason i started this topic

Comment: I also think that, especially within "the art circle", "the art circle" means *the collection of people who deal in art- i.e., artists, dealers,  critics, and collectors.*  It can often be qualified by region or subject matter:  the NY art circle, or the post-modernist art circle.  If your intention is to talk about the *people* when you say "art circle" then your use is appropriate.  But if not, I'd recommend using a different phrase to avoid the ambiguity as J.R. has done.